# Vlookup doesn't seem to cooperate

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, finance

I have the following Code for bank reconciliation which involves checking each cell in column D of sheet1 (bank statements) and see if it exists in column M of Sheet 2. If it doesn't flag it by saving it to arrOutput.

Being a new user, and because I could not attach the spreadsheet, I have links to what Sheet 1 and 2 look like.

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKFpn.png)
[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrJwa.png)

```
 Sub abc_3()

 Dim i As Long, ii
 Dim arrBank As Range
 Dim arrAccounting As Range
 Dim arrOutput

 Dim temp As Variant

 ' setting bank transaction into range
 Set bank = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D25:E25" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)

 ' setting accounting transactions into range
 Set books = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("M1:N1" & Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row)


 'everytime time the program is run arrOutput must be cleared. 3000 is an arbitrary number I chose because there will likely never be a higher number of transactions than this.
 ReDim arrOutput(1 To 3000, 1 To 2)   

 ii = 0

 ' The main function of the program.. looping through every bank transaction checking if it can be found in accounting transactions,
 ' if it cannot be found, i.e error is thrown then save the cell to arrOutput because it needs to be flagged for checking.
 ' if it can be found, then ignore and check next bank transaction.
 ' Currently, the procedure is supposed to compare only Sheet1 credit transactions with Sheet2 credit transactions, therefore filter only credit transactions. 
 For Each cell In bank.Cells     'problem here is comparing both Column D and E of Sheet 1 whereas it should be comparing only column D.
     If cell <> "" Then       'this is to avoid checking non-credit transactions.
         On Error Resume Next
         temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell, books, 2, False)
         If Err.Number <> 0 Then
             MsgBox "Bank Transaction " & cell & " could not be found in Books Transaction history"
             arrOutput(ii, 1) = cell
             arrOutput(ii, 2) = ""
             ii = ii + 1
         End If
     End If
 Next

'all cells checked then dump arrOutput to range "L4" for reading
 Range("l4").Resize(3000, 2) = arrOutput

 bank.ClearContents
 books.ClearContents

 End Sub
```

The problem is that on every cell I get MSG "Bank Transaction " & cell & " could not be found in Books Transaction history". Consequently, Every cell gets saved to arrOutput and saved to Sheets("Sheet3").Range("L4") making me wonder whether Vlookup is not cooperating or I didn't setup the error handler correctly.

Looking forward to getting some help.. been stuck on this for too long. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top row of your module.  Get rid of `On Error Resume Next` so you can see where the error is.

Comment: Thank for the reply Mark. I got rid of what you suggested and now getting "Run-time error '1004' unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction Class" 

I had this error before and could not find anything on stackoverflow that helped except an online post in forum suggesting to trap the error which I did using `On Error Resume Next`. I am now where I was more than a week ago.

Comment: You trapped the error? No you ignored it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you should qualify the ranges. 2) `:E25` should be `:D` and `:N1` should be `:M`. 3) Use Option Explicit and use the variables you declared (you declare some variable names but then you use other names...). 4) Finally, use `Find` instead of `VLookup`, since you only want to check the existence of the value, not a corresponding other value.

```
Option Explicit
Sub abc_3()
     Dim bank As Range, books As Range, cell As Range
     With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set bank = .Range("D26:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
     End With
     With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
         Set books = .Range("M2:M" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row)
     End With

     Dim ii As Long, x As Range, arrOutput(1 To 3000, 1 To 2)
     For Each cell In bank.Cells
         If Trim(cell.Value) <> "" Then
             Set x = books.Find(cell.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
             If x Is Nothing Then
                 ii = ii + 1
                 arrOutput(ii, 1) = cell.Value
                 MsgBox "Bank Transaction " & cell.Value & " could not be found in Books Transaction history"
             Else
                 x.Value = ""
             End If
         End If
     Next
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("l4").Resize(3000, 2) = arrOutput
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. I applied your recommended changes however I now get "compile error: variable not defined" on "Cell" after the "For each" loop statement

Comment: Edit: I removed the Options Explicit statement and it ran without the compile time error. However, the output has not changed from what I can see. I still get every "" cell value in column D and E and some empty "" cell values saved to arrOutput..

Comment: @user2299013  There are lot of mistakes, I only focused on the main ones. But now you can try the edited code, I re-wrote it completely.

Comment: Thank you so so much! Works perfectly!

Comment: For some reason when I run the code on the work computer on the actual data (in comparison to home computer on sample data) it doesn't work at all. In fact, it doesn't seem to care about the line `If cell.Value <> "" Then` or `If books.Find(cell.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole) Is Nothing Then` because it outputs empty cells and cells that already exist into "l4". I am trying to google this.

Comment: I have tried `Application.EnableEvents = true ` but still does not work as expected.

Comment: Back on home computer and still code doesn't work on the actual data set.. Weirdly, its as if it is running a different piece of code because it is not following instructions...

Comment: @user2299013 We need to find what is special in the actual data set? and what is the pattern the code is showing when you run it step-by-step? BTW, make sure you have only one Excel workbook open when you run it, or even better, remove the use of `ÀctiveWorkbook.` altogether from the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am getting a quite stressed because I have only got this week left of my training program at the firm and have nothing to show for it. I haven't figured out what is special about the actual data set yet but the pattern the code is showing is for each and every value in bank "column D" it cannot find it in books "column M".

Comment: Changed ranges to text. better looking output came out...  just checking values will comment back.

Comment: checked the accuracy of the flagged numbers saved to arrOutput manually. They all check out except for this 1 case.. Empty Cells seem to get saved, it seems like the filter/check `If cell.Value <> "" Then` doesn't prove effective.

Comment: Is it possible that these cells contains space characters? If so we can try `If Trim(cell.Value) <> ""` or better yet: `If IsNumeric(cell.Value)`

Comment: Dear A.S.H, I have met the problem i was expecting. There are certain values in the accounting system that show up multiple times in the Bank statement. For example, when reconciling the value 21.25 is a typical bank charge that shows up twice in the accounting system but thrice in the bank statement. The current code would check out correctly, saying that 21.25 of the accounting statement is in the bank account and vice versa for all the 21.25 values and it will never be flagged. Is there a way to remove the value afterwards i.e by discarding after pairing so we can flag the last 21.25?

Comment: @user2299013 I added this last requirement, but could not test it. Please try the edited code.

Comment: Dear A.S.H, sorry for the late reply i was testing code. I have edited the code as can be seen above, adding the last requirement of `cell.Value = ""` when setting x.Value = "".. I am still testing this but it looks like it is working.

Comment: The code works and is fully functional. You have been extremely helpful in finishing this code on-time. Thank you very much. If there is anything I can for you please do let me know.

Comment: @user2299013 I am glad to know that all is going fine for you. Thank you :)